# How to force HttpWebRequest to use cache in ASP.NET environment?

Tags: .net, asp.net, caching, httpwebrequest

In my ASP.NET app I use HttpWebRequest for fetching external resources which I'd like to be cached. Consider the following code:

```
var req = WebRequest.Create("http://google.com/");
req.CachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.CacheIfAvailable);
var resp = req.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(resp.IsFromCache);
var answ = (new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream())).ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(answ.Length);
```

HttpWebRequest uses IE cache, so when I run it as normal user (in tiny cmd test app), data is cached to `%userprofile%\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files` and next responses are read from cache.

I thought that when such code is run inside ASP.NET app, data will be cached to `...\ASPNET\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files` but it is not and cache is never used.

What I am doing wrong? How to force HttpWebRequest to use cache in ASP.NET environment?

Comment: What account is your ASP.NET app running under? The cache will be created under that account.

Comment: @feroze: The app is running under ASPNET account and I know the Temporary Internet Files path from examining Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache. 

The problem is not that I don't know where cache entries are created but they aren't created at all.

Comment: Can you add a line to close and dispose the response object: resp.Close(); and then check if you are still having problems?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the cache manually in your code like this:

```
 Cache.Insert("request", req, Nothing, DateTime.Now, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), TimeSpan.Zero)
```

You can use this Method like you would use caching with in web.config.

Comment: I'll probably end up implementing custom cache but I was hoping for some straightforward "out of the box" solution...

Comment: I think there is no out of the box for your problem but this shouldn't be a big problem to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but another thing to consider regarding this issue is the IE security settings for the user account the ASP.NET application is running as. HTTP caching (CachePolicy.Level = Default, HTTP cacheable resources) was not working for our application until we added the remote host to the Trusted Sites list.

This article was useful for our cache troubleshooting: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/19/wininet-temporary-internet-files-cache-and-explorer-folder-view.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I would suspect that `HttpWebRequest` respects cache headers from the resource regardless of your stated desires.

Check the response headers and ensure that the resource is not explicitly asking to not be cached.

Comment: I suspected headers too so I build a tiny cmd app that makes httprequest to the same resource. In cmd app it's cached. And in ASP.NET app it's not.